# How to format a python __str__ output

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm working on OpenStack and I see a lot of object written to a long line of string in log file. E.g.

```
vol={'migration_status': None, 'availability_zone': u'nova', 'terminated_at': None, 'updated_at': datetime.datetime(2015, 5, 15, 7, 0, 11), 'provider_geometry': None, 'snapshot_id': None, 'ec2_id': None, 'mountpoint': u'/dev/sdb', 'deleted_at': None, 'id': u'83a5ade7-275e-4ffd-b494-a4c2c9a169d1', 'size': 10L, 'user_id': u'2b5cd66674d24c4f94138002d96f5f96', 'attach_time': u'2015-05-13T06:12:35.749100', 'attached_host': None, 'display_description': None, 'volume_admin_metadata': [<cinder.db.sqlalchemy.models.VolumeAdminMetadata object at 0x7fbd834f52d0>, <cinder.db.sqlalchemy.models.VolumeAdminMetadata object at 0x7fbd834f58d0>], 'encryption_key_id': None, 'project_id': u'9ba90732bdba43dcbd49e111cbe92458', 'launched_at': datetime.datetime(2015, 5, 13, 5, 56, 33), 'scheduled_at': datetime.datetime(2015, 5, 13, 5, 56, 31), 'status': u'available', 'volume_type_id': None, 'deleted': False, 'provider_location': None, 'host': u'controller01', 'source_volid': None, 'provider_auth': None, 'display_name': u'parallel_200_1-my_vol107-umrnk5jchjwo', 'instance_uuid': u'a81b355d-d240-4888-93a1-7e10822a777f', 'bootable': False, 'created_at': datetime.datetime(2015, 5, 13, 5, 56, 31), 'attach_status': u'attached', 'volume_type': None, '_name_id': None, 'volume_metadata': [], 'metadata': {u'readonly': u'False', u'attached_mode': u'rw'}}
```

I want to have a way to format this output to a json-like format to be more readable. Something like:

```
{
  'migration_status': None,
  'availability_zone': u'nova',
  ...
}
```

How could I do that?

I have a follow-up question. All the answers involves establishing a dict or list object. But I got errors if I have the following in the string from log file:

1. 'volume_admin_metadata': [,] - error: SyntaxError: invalid syntax (at '<')
2. 'updated_at': datetime.datetime(2015, 5, 15, 7, 0, 11) - error: ​NameError: name 'datetime' is not defined
3. "encrypted": false - error: NameError: name 'false' is not defined
4. "source_volid": null - error: NameError: name 'null' is not defined

Is there some utility that can take care of this syntax error automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Except the `pprint`, you can also try `json`

```
>>> import json
>>> jhon = {'name': 'Jhon', 'age': 12, 'hobbies': ['football', 'games', 'running'], 'family': {'father': 'David', 'mother': 'Rose'}}
>>> print(json.dumps(jhon, indent=4))
{
    "age": 12, 
    "name": "jhon", 
    "family": {
        "father": "David", 
        "mother": "Rose"
    }, 
    "hobbies": [
        "football", 
        "games", 
        "running"
    ]
}
```

Since your have something like `'updated_at': datetime.datetime(2015, 5, 15, 7, 0, 11)`, you can use `json.dumps(blabla, indent=4, default=str)`

Answer (score 2):

Python has a [`pprint` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html) which can format output like you describe.

```
>>> import pprint
>>> stuff = ['spam', 'eggs', 'lumberjack', 'knights', 'ni']
>>> stuff.insert(0, stuff[:])
>>> pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)
>>> pp.pprint(stuff)
[   ['spam', 'eggs', 'lumberjack', 'knights', 'ni'],
    'spam',
    'eggs',
    'lumberjack',
    'knights',
    'ni']
```

For use within a `__str__` method, `pprint.pformat` would be the most convenient function.